# Alter table add column AFTER in derby database

Tags: derby, alter

Is there a way in a derby database to add a column after another just like mysql does?

Comment: I wish they would add this too. I like the schema to look exactly the same whether it's brand new or migrated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe so. Column ordering isn't really a standard SQL feature. Well-written db applications shouldn't care about column ordering. You can specify the order of the columns in your output by naming the columns in your SQL statement as in:

create table t (a int, b int, c int );

select b, c, a from t;

Comment: Actually, it's just if someone opens the DB editor, the table does not look logic then.